# Searching in Rails, Search also non consecutive words

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a basic search function in order to search for 3 fields in my database.
The search function is as follows:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    @search_out = Array.new
    @prod_out = find(:all, :conditions => ['name ILIKE ? or supplier_code ILIKE ? or    ppd_code ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
      @prod_out.each do |prod| 
        prod.quantities.each do |quants|
          @search_out << quants
        end
      end
      return @search_out
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Now its working all great, but I want to add an option that lets say I have name entries in my DB which are "Jack and Jill Movie" and "Jack and Janet Movie"
That if I write in the search field: "Jack Movie", it will return me both of those entries.

Overall, an ability to search for words in the search field and receive also entries which those words aren't consecutive in them. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Well I actually found a pretty simple way to do this.

I added this in my function before the "find" itself:

```
@arr = search.split(' ')
@arr.collect! {|x| x + "%" }
search = @arr.join
```

That way I'm adding a '%' between each word which gives a wildcard, so now I can find words which aren't necessarily consecutive because there is a wildcard between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Regexp feature of Mysql

```
some_query.where("name REGEXP ?", "#{search.split(' ').join(".*")}")
```

You obviously need to filter out regular expression special characters from search string before using it in a regular expression..

[mysql documentation about it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html)

Comment: You can use Regexp.escape(search) to escape the input.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm actually using PostgreSQL (hence the ILIKE and not LIKE), so I'll try looking into regexing in that

Answer (score 0):

There are some full-featured search engines like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com), and they can be easily integrated into a Rails app by using gems such as [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com) and [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/). Postgres also has a built-in search engine, so it might be easier to setup. This is more powerful but at the same time more complex solution.

If you want to get an overview on each of them, [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=30) is a great resource for that.